# Examples of kernels between sets of vectors

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick

Can anyone give some examples of widely-used kernels between sets of vectors?

A kernel between sets of vectors is a positive semidefinite map $k:(S,T)\mapsto k(S,T)\in \mathbb{R}$ where $S$ and $T$ are sets of vectors (i.e., $S=\{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_m\}$, $T=\{t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n\}$, and $s_i,t_j\in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Thank you!

Comment: There are quite a few in the [Gaussian process for Machine Learning book](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW4.pdf). Probably the most common is the squared exponential kernel, where you give a positive definite matrix $\Sigma$ and the kernel is $\kappa(x,y; \Sigma) = \exp\left(x^t \Sigma y\right)$. Using this kernel is akin to assuming a Gaussian relationship between the components of $x_i$.  Another excellent reference is [the kernel cookbook](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~duvenaud/cookbook/index.html), which has a good set of visualizations to go with it.

Comment: @StefanJorgensen I think you missed that the inputs to the kernel are supposed to be _sets_ of vectors, not single vectors.

Comment: Indeed. But is it fundamentally different? The collection of vectors $S = \{s_1,\dots,s_m\}$ is just a matrix, which one could vectorize and use the standard kernels for, right?

Comment: @StefanJorgensen Sure...if you're willing to only support sets of a single fixed size, and to require factorially times as many inputs for the learning method to pick up on the set's permutation invariance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the most common one in machine learning usage is the mean map kernel (the kernel induced by the maximum mean discrepancy [MMD] distance). Here we define an auxiliary kernel $\kappa$, and then $$k(S, T) = \frac{1}{mn} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n \kappa(s_i, t_j).$$

This essentially makes the assumption that $S$ and $T$ are iid samples from some distributions $P$ and $Q$, and estimates a distance between $P$ and $Q$. If you use a Gaussian RBF kernel of bandwidth $\sigma$, the mean map embedding distance converges to a multiple of the $L_2$ distance as $\sigma \to 0$, but you'd typically use some fixed larger $\sigma$, in which case your statistical estimation properties are better.

You can see an overview of many such kernels and estimators of them in, uh, [my PhD thesis from last year](http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/2016/abstracts/16-128.html).