# Kernels in Gaussian Processes

Tags: gaussian-process, kernel-trick

I am trying to understand intuitively how a kernel works in a Gaussian process. I know that GP are distributions over functions, in short you have the model $y = f(x)+\epsilon$ and the $f(x)$ follows a Gaussian process

$GP(m(x),K(x,x^{\prime}))$.

After deriving the conditional distribution we arrive at the predictive equations (with noise):

$\hat{f}=K(x,x^{\prime})(K(x,x)+\sigma^{2}I)^{-1}y$ for the mean

and

$cov(f)=K(x^{\prime},x^{\prime})-K(x^{\prime},x)(K(x,x)+\sigma^{2}I)^{-1}K(x,x^{\prime})$ for the covariance.

The covariance kernel is the SE (Squared Exponential):

$k_{f}(x_{i},x_{j}) = \sigma^{2}exp(-\frac{1}{2\ell^{2}}\sum_{j=1}^{q}(x_{i,j}-x_{k,j})^{2})$

I know that a kernel, when we have a vector with inputs $x$ and size $(n)$, has dimensions $(n\times n)$. But how it works in multidimensional environment?
For example, the covariance above $cov(f)$ with one dimensional inputs $(n)$ and for a single test point $(p = 1)$ will have the form:

$(p \times p) - (p \times n)(n \times n)(n \times p)$ which gives a scalar (the variance).

I can't comprehend how the above equation will work when we accept as input a matrix $(n \times d)$ size instead.

Comment: You might find [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257969/examples-of-kernels-between-sets-of-vectors) helpful. Also the [Kernel cookbook](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~duvenaud/cookbook/index.html) is a great resource for more standard kernels.

Comment: What is $d$? (The dimension of *what*?) Also, looks like the question is asking about some issue with multidimensional something rather than "understand intuitively how a kernel works"?

Comment: I have been clear on that. "We accept as input a matrix with dimensions $(n x d)$, so is the dimensions of matrix $x$. Now the question asks how the kernel works in a multi-dimension, in which case you are right. I do not state that explicitly but rather I have put forward an example, as the calculation of covariance function depends on the kernel. So, in that example, if we have a multidimensional input $x$, how do we calculate the covariance function? Thanks

Comment: Scrap that, I just realised that I also state "how the kernel works in a multidimensional environment". And then I provide an example.

Comment: Please read the question carefully, "one dimensional inputs (n)".  (p) is the size of the test point. I do state that. So you have as input a one dimensional vector with size n and a scalar test point. I do not know how to be more clear on that. Yes, the question asks "how it works in a multi dimensional environment".

Comment: I clearly state how it would work when we accept an input matrix nxd. In the whole question I'm referring to the inputs, I haven't said anything about multivariate regression, a multidimensional $y$.

Comment: I have left an answer to what I now think the question is asking - have I understood correctly and does the answer answer the question? (I removed some of my previous comments but would still like the question to more explicitly state that it is about inputs being in $\mathbb{R}^d$: the $n\times d$ "input matrix" could refer to an "input" to some calculation rather than the collection of input points in the training data, and the SE kernel being defined for $q$-dimensional inputs  instead of $d$ does not help) .

Comment: Yes, your answer is perfect. And very nicely commented. :)

Comment: I will make the changes as you suggested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Notation / setting

We are considering a GP regression model:
\begin{equation}
y_i = f(x_i) + \epsilon_i
\end{equation}
where $y_i\in \mathbb{R}$,$x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $f$ a Gaussian process (whose realizations are functions $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$), 
\begin{equation}
f \sim \mathrm{GP}(m(x_i), \kappa(x_i,x_j)).
\end{equation}
$n$ datapoints $(y_1,x_1), (y_2,x_2), (y_3,x_3),\ldots, (y_n,x_n)$ are given. (I  use $\kappa$ to distinguish the function from the matrices $K(\cdot,\cdot)$ that contain values of $\kappa$ evaluated at certain points. The question denotes both by $K$)

#### How to handle $d$-dimensional inputs

The question covers computing the posterior predictive distribution for a test point (or $p$ test points) in the case $d=1$ and asks how to extend to the general $d=2,3,\ldots$.

Answer: nothing changes and the formulas from the one-dimensional case work as well in this case. Note that $m$ is then a function from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\kappa$ a function from $\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

So, for example the matrix denoted by $K(x,x)$ in the question is a $n\times n$ matrix for which $K(x,x)_{i,j} = \kappa(x_i, x_j)$  ($x_i$ and $x_j$ are $d$-dimensional but since $\kappa$ maps two $d$-dimensional vectors to a scalar, $\kappa(x_i, x_j)$ is a scalar. Similarly for $K(x,x')$ and $K(x',x')$ where $x'$ are the test points.

Thus, the dimensions of the matrices in the predictive covariance equation are $(p\times p) - (p \times n)\,(n \times n)\,(n \times p)$ independent of whether the elements of the matrices are obtained by evaluating a function $\kappa(\cdot,\cdot)$ whose arguments are $1$-dimensional of a function $\kappa(\cdot, \cdot)$ whose arguments are $d$-dimensional. In fact, the inputs could even be in some space other than $\mathbb{R}^d$ (such as if we have a categorical predictor) as long as a positive-definite covariance function can be defined.

#### An extra remark about the SE kernel appearing in the question

The question mentions the SE kernel 
\begin{equation}
k_{f}(x_{i},x_{j}) = \sigma^{2}\exp\!\Big(-\frac{1}{2\ell^{2}}\sum_{j=1}^{q}(x_{i,j}-x_{k,j})^{2}\Big)
\end{equation}
Note that this is already a function from $\mathbb{R}^q \times \mathbb{R}^q$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (with scalar inputs there would be no "$x_{i,j}$ and $x_{k,j}$" for different values of $j$. And $q$ should be $d$ if $d$ is the dimension of inputs.

Optionally, the length scale $\ell$ could be made different for each input dimension as $\ell_{j}$, such that the term $\frac{1}{2\ell_{j}^{2}}$ is instead placed inside the summation

Comment: Especially for the last part, about the kernel. Very helpful indeed! I should delete my previous 'answer'