# Does radial basis function kernel have a coefficient?

Tags: scikit-learn, gaussian-process, rbf-kernel

I found there are two forms of `RBF` function.

1. There is a coefficient before $\exp$
   $$
   k_{f}\left(x_{i}, x_{j}\right)=\sigma^{2} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2 \ell^{2}} \sum_{j=1}^{q}\left(x_{i, j}-x_{k, j}\right)^{2}\right)
   $$
   which can be found in :

   [Kernels in Gaussian Processes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298734/kernels-in-gaussian-processes/506705#506705)

   [https://nipunbatra.github.io/blog/ml/2020/06/26/gp-understand.html#:~:text=The%20most%20commonly%20used%20kernel,exponential%20kernel%20%E2%80%93%20all%20are%20equivalent.&text=It%20has%20two%20parameters%2C%20described,2%20and%20the%20lengthscale%20l.&text=rbf](https://nipunbatra.github.io/blog/ml/2020/06/26/gp-understand.html#:%7E:text=The%20most%20commonly%20used%20kernel,exponential%20kernel%20%E2%80%93%20all%20are%20equivalent.&text=It%20has%20two%20parameters%2C%20described,2%20and%20the%20lengthscale%20l.&text=rbf).
2. There is no coefficient before $\exp$
   $$
   K\left(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}^{\prime}\right)=\exp \left(-\frac{\left\|\mathbf{x} \quad \mathbf{x}^{\prime}\right\|^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}\right)
   $$
   which can be found in wikipedia and `scikit-learn`:

   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel

   https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#gp-kernels

What’s the difference between the two forms? Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent. The point of basis functions is to be able to use weighted linear combinations of them to approximate other functions, and the weighted linear combinations of these two give exactly the same set of approximations.

Comment: The coefficient $\sigma$ in first equation is weight in `weighted linear combinations`. Am I right? But in the second link, it said `It has two parameters, described as the variance $\sigma$  and the lengthscale $l$`.   why we donot need the variance $\sigma$ in GaussianProcess in scikit-learn's implementation？

Comment: They're equivalent for some applications but not all. E.g. when specifying the covariance function of a Gaussian process, the scale factor $\sigma^2$ in the first form is very important

Comment: Everyone who uses the second form to define the covariance function will put in a scale factor, though.